# Svelte reactivity with D3

Tags: svelte

I have an SVG constructed using d3, that depends on the value of an `<input>` element on the page. I'd like for the SVG to update whenever the input value has changed. There is simple [reactivity demo in the tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/reactive-declarations). However, the [example using d3](https://svelte.dev/repl/8722c32f4e1a44a98e3a3fc8a095b2d7?version=3.5.3) puts the code in `onMount` and this seems to break reactivity.

Here's an example:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    import * as d3 from 'd3';
    
    var word = "Hello";
    let container;

    onMount(() => { d3.select(container).text(word); });
</script>

<p><input bind:value={word}></p>
<p>You typed "<span bind:this={container}></span>"</p>
```

You'll find that typing in the text box does not cause the text in the `span` to update:

A bonus would be for the SVG to only update after a delay, so that the user has time to finish what they are typing. (The real SVG is much heavier than the toy example above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`d3` depends on DOM access, whenever that is the case you usually can replace the `onMount` with a reactive statement (`$:`) that is guarded by a check on the DOM elements being used.

This only works correctly if you prevent additions and removals from the DOM to compound. This may not be the case with `d3`.

For this simple example you could do:

```js
$: if (container) {
  d3.select(container).text(word);
}
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5edb74b845df42e0bd9852d69b6691f4?version=3.49.0)

Depending on what you are trying to do, you could also just ditch `d3` and construct the SVG using Svelte.